# Which Scripture mentions Mangala as son of Varaha?

Tags: varaha, bhumi

I heard that lord Varaha begot 2 sons with Bhumi when bhumi took form of varahi. One of the sons is Narakasura aka Baumasura. I am looking for who is the other son. I found in wiki that Mangala (Lord of Mars) is the other son, but I need scriptural evidence for the same. Any one know which scriptures describes Mangala as son of Varaha and Bhumi.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Brahma Vaivarta Purana mentions Mangala as the son born through the union of Bhudevi and Varaha.

**Brahma vaivarta purana Prakriti khanda Chapter 8**

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Devī Bhāgavata Purāṇa explicitly states that Maṅgala was son of Varāha (avatāra) & Pṛthvi.

> viṣṇorvarāharūpasya patnī sā śrutisammatā // 
> tatputro maṅgalo jñeyo ghaṭeśo maṅgalātmaja / 
> ~ Devī Bhāgavata Purāṇa ([9.9.23b-24a](https://archive.org/details/QWtF_devi-bhagvata-vol-2-khemraj/page/n399/mode/2up?view=theater))

Nārāyaṇa says (to Nārada), "*It's established by śruti that Pṛthvi is the patnī of Varāharūpī Viṣṇu. Their son was Maṅgala, and Maṅgala's son was Ghaṭeśa*."

Later, Nārada asks more regarding birth of Maṅgala ([9.9.26](https://archive.org/details/QWtF_devi-bhagvata-vol-2-khemraj/page/n399/mode/2up?view=theater)) and then Nārāyaṇa recounts the kathā as to how Maṅgala's birth happened, in ([9.9.29-32](https://archive.org/details/QWtF_devi-bhagvata-vol-2-khemraj/page/n399/mode/2up?view=theater)).

Answer (score -1):

Lohitanga aka Mangala (Mars) aka Bhauma is the son of Bhagawan Rudra and Earth.

Shiva Purana 2.3.10.:

> 12. Thus Śiva remained for a long time eliminating the three attributes, and unaffected by aberrations. The lord Himself, the controller of illusion remained in the state of the Supreme Brahman.
> 13. Then He gave up trance. Many years elapsed. What happened thereafter, I shall now recount to you.
> 14. **The drops of sweat caused by exhaustion fell on the Earth from the lord’s forehead and took the shape of a child immediately.**
> 15. O sage, the child was tawny-coloured and had four arms. He was comely in features. His brilliance was supermundane and unbearable to others.
> 16. Like a common child he cried in front of the Great lord who was engaged in worldly activities.
> 17. Afraid of Śiva, the Earth pondered deeply over it and appeared before him in the guise of a good lady.
> 18. She lifted up the child immediately and held him to her chest. Lovingly she suckled the child with her excellent breast milk that flowed over her body.
> 19. She kissed the child’s face lovingly and petted him smilingly. In the absence of Satī she herself acted as his mother in the interest of lord Śiva.
> 20. Śiva knew that she was the Earth. Śiva, the cause of protection and enjoyment, the immanent soul, on seeing her activities became contented and eagerly said to her laughingly.
> 21. **“O Earth, you are blessed. Rear this child of mine lovingly, born of my glittering drops of sweat over you.**
> 22. Although the child is born of the sweat of my body, O Earth, he will be famous in the world after your name. He will be a bestower of pleasures and will be free from the three distresses always.
> 23. This boy of yours will be a bestower of lands and will have good qualities. He will make me too happy. Accept him with pleasure”.
>
> .
>
> 25. The Earth too, as Śiva bade her, returned to her abode along with the child. She was extremely happy.
> 26. **The child acquired the name Bhauma (son of the Earth). He attained youth immedately. For a long time he worshipped lord Śiva at Kāśī.**
> 27. **By the grace of lord Śiva, the son of the Earth, acquired the status of a planet. He went to the heavenly sphere beyond the region of Venus.**

Skanda Purana 5.3.148.:

> **He should adore Lohita (Mars) devoutly** with sweet scents, garlands and ornaments. The idol should be installed on the ground and smeared with red sandal-paste.
>
> Uttering “Obeisance to Aṅgāraka” he should adore on the pericarp of the lotus figure (drawn). Then on the petals beginning with the one in the east, he should perform the worship uttering respectively. “Obeisance to Kuja”, **“Obeisance to Bhūmi-Putra”,** “Obeisance to Raktāṅga”, “Obeisance to Suvāsas”, **“Obeisance to Harakopodbhava” (‘born of the anger of Hara’), “Obeisance to Svedaja” (‘born of sweat’),** “Obeisance to Atibāhu”, (‘of extremely powerful arms’) and “Obeisance to Sarvakāmaprada” (‘bestower of all desires’).
>
> After duly worshipping thus, he (the devotee) should offer the Arghya in accordance with the injunction. Then he utters the Mantra: **“Obeisance to you, O son of Earth, O highly powerful one, O deity born of the sweat of the Pināka-bearing Lord, O Lohitāṅga (red-bodied one). O Aṅgāraka, I make, obeisance to you.”**

Padma Purana 1.81.:

> 40. Then speaking to the gods, Śiva vomitted Śukra. The foetus fell down on the ground, so he was known as Bhauma.
> 41. Śukra, having spoken to Śiva, gladly went to the demons. **Thus Bhauma (i.e. Mars) is born as a portion of Śiva and from the Earth (also).**
> 42. His worship should be done by those of pious vows on the fourth day (falling) on Tuesday, when his position at birth is not favourable, when he passes from one to another zodiacal sign, or has entered an undesirable zodiacial sign.
>
> 43-44a. Bhauma, with his figure drawn in a triangle or a circle, and being worshipped with red flowers and anointments, gives knowledge and wealth, sons, happiness and glory. What again do you want to hear?

I hope this clarifies all your queries. Prd..

Comment: As you know, due to kalpabheda, there's difference in the accounts of birth of some devatās, in different Purāṇas. You can see the other two answers to this question, both cite Purāṇas to show that Maṅgala was the son of Varāha (avatāra) & Pṛthvi.

Comment: Yes, i know that's why after seeing the other answer that day, as you can already see i have edited my answer also then and there only.